# How to factor out $5^x$ from $5^{x+3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I know this is basic but I am having some confusion here. I need to write $5^x+5^{x+3}$ as $A \times 5^x$. I see on khanacademy and symbolab that I am supposed to factor out $5^x$ as it is a common factor however i don't understand how $5^x$ is a common factor of $5^3$. Any understanding would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: It's $5^x(1+5^3)$, if you take$5^x$ as common from the given expression.

Comment: "i don't understand how $5^x$ is a common factor of $5^3$." What you really must understand is that $5^x$ is a common factor of $5^x$ and $5^{x+3}$.

Comment: @SamKha Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** recall that $5^{x+3}=5^x \cdot 5^3$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the speedy response. I see how to factor 5^x from 5^x+3 however i don't understand how to obtain the answer 5^x x 126. I have 5^x + (5^x x 125). how can i simplify further from this stage?

Comment: @SamKha Use the fact that $a + b\cdot a = (1+b)\cdot a$

Comment: Sorry to see you withdraw from the moderator election, Zachary. I hope you'll reconsider.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$5^x+5^{x+3}=5^x+5^x\cdot 5^3=5^x(1+125)=126\cdot 5^x$$

Answer (score 0):

Using index laws,
$$5^{x + 3} = 5^x \cdot 5^3 = 125 \cdot 5^x.$$

Note that this is different from the situation $5^x + 5^3$, where $5^x$ would indeed have to be a factor of $5^3$ in order to (cleanly) take it out as a divisor.